# Checking out from a git tree

Tags: linux, git

I need to checkout this libunwind port for FreeBSD,

http://people.freebsd.org/~kib/git/libunwind.git/

I've never used git before and when i tried to checkout using the command

**git checkout http://people.freebsd.org/~kib/git/libunwind.git/**

I get the following error,

**fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should do it:

```
git clone http://people.freebsd.org/~kib/git/libunwind.git/
```

If you are coming from svn background, read [this](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html).

Comment: Thanks :) I tried that, but its showing another error like "Connection timed out, unable to establish a socket" - guess i'll have to sort it iut.

Answer (score 0):

You should read a basic tutorial on git before trying to use it. Git is not a centralised system. You should `clone` if you want to get a repository.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to clone it, no?  It will create a copy onto your system:

```
git clone http://people.freebsd.org/~kib/git/libunwind.git/ local-dir
```